# compare query in Union in sql

Tags: sql-server, union

hi Programmers!
               I have to compare the select query between  union query

My code goes like this:

```
           select emp_id,type from
           (
               select emp_id,'leave' as type 
                 from tbl_emp_info 
                where emp_id like'5_2' or emp_id like '602' 
           ) as t1
           union 
           select emp_id,type from
           (
               select emp_id,'weekend'as type 
                 from tbl_emp_off_info 
                where emp_id like'6_2' 
           ) t2 t1.emp_id!=t2.emp_id
```

I need to compare these two select query

```
      As i need the result like

          EMP_ID      TYPE

          512        leave
          612       weekend
```

But not like

```
          EMP_ID      TYPE


          512        leave
          612        leave
          612       weekend
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you (SQL Server 2005 and up).

```
;WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT emp_id, 'leave' AS [type]
    FROM tbl_emp_info 
    WHERE emp_id LIKE '5_2' OR emp_id LIKE '602'
)
, t2 AS
(
    SELECT emp_id, 'weekend' AS [type]
    FROM tbl_emp_info 
    WHERE emp_id LIKE '6_2'
)
SELECT emp_id, [type]
FROM t1
WHERE emp_id NOT IN (SELECT emp_id FROM t2)
UNION
SELECT emp_id, [type]
FROM t2
```

For SQL Server 2000 you'll need to duplicate one of the WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT emp_id, 'leave' AS [type]
FROM tbl_emp_info 
WHERE (emp_id LIKE '5_2' OR emp_id LIKE '602')
AND NOT (emp_id LIKE '6_2')
UNION 
SELECT emp_id, 'weekend' AS [type]
FROM tbl_emp_info 
WHERE (emp_id LIKE '6_2')
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it gives error like:       Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'.  Actually i use sql server 2000 ,Does it occur due to its version.

Comment: I checked this code in sql server 2005 and it works but not in sql server 2000 , is there anyway to perform this action in sql server 2000?

Comment: I've added a solution for SQL Server 2000